# SSIS - Cannot permanently change the External Columns from ODBC Source

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, etl, data-conversion

In SSIS, I am trying to pull in table data from a large Data warehouse for some analysis in Excel.  I have written the following query:

```
SELECT journal_name        AS Journal_Name,
       division            AS DIV,
       account             AS Acct,
       cost_center         AS CC,
       effective_date      AS Effective_Date,
       effective_month     AS Month,
       effective_year      AS Year,
       posted_date         AS Posted_Date,
       source              AS Source,
       line_description    AS Line_Description,
       category            AS Category,
       entered_amount    AS E_Entered_Amount,
       entered_currency    AS E_Currency,
       functional_amount   AS Fuctional_Amount,
       functional_currency AS F_Currency
FROM   corp.source
WHERE  ( (division  = 'C301' )
         AND ( account  LIKE '%' )
         AND ( cost_center = '8D' )
         AND ( effective_month BETWEEN '01' AND '10' )
         AND ( effective_year  = '2019' ) )
ORDER BY posted_date
```

I am doing this with ODBC Source as I have taken Oracle connector info from a Microsoft Access tool. I run the parse in the ODBC screen and I look at the preview and get no issues.  However, when I try to run this package just to make sure the connection works, I get:

```
===================================

Package Validation Error (Package Validation Error)

===================================

Error at Expression Task [Microsoft.SqlServer.ExpressionTask]: A null or empty expression is not valid.  Specify an expression.
Error at Expression Task: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DtsPackagesFolderProjectFeature.ExecuteTaskOrPackage(ProjectItem prjItem, String taskPath)
```

I'm not quite sure what column is causing the error.  I have dealt with this exact same data in the past and was able to change all of the data coming in the Advanced Editor into Wide Strings [WSTR] when using OLE DB, then used data conversion to fix it and it worked very well.  However, every time I try and change the type of the external data in this ODBC source advanced editor, it keeps resetting to the original data types.  Is there a better way to do this, or is there a reason I cannot reset that incoming data to WSTR to deal with it?

Thanks.

Comment: The error is coming from the Expression Task named `Expression Task` in your package and, as far as I can tell, it's related to your query. Find that expression task referenced in the error message you posted and figure out why there's a NULL or empty expression.

Comment: You are correct - buried at the bottom out of sight was a blank expression task. Once I removed it, it is still not working but that is a separate question and I'll investigate that a bit on here.  Appreciate the help on such a dumb issue on my part.

Comment: I'm sure you understood my previous comment, but I just noticed a typo that changes my implied meaning. In case someone from the future sees my comment and is confused, I meant to say `...it's unrelated to your query`